# What in Kubuntu could be limiting available cpu cores? (only half are utilized in Plasma)

Tags: kubuntu, kde, cpu, cgroup

I am running Kubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on a 12-core/24-thread AMD Ryzen 5900X.

The problem I am having is that many tasks running in KDE/plasma appear to be limited by CPU affinity to only 12 of the 24 threads on the CPU, when observing via htop.  For example, I can start a konsole session, and run multiple parallel instances of a (software-based) video encoder on some large files.  Collectively those **should** fully use the CPU (as it does in Windows when I dual-boot), but that is not currently happening in Kubuntu - htop shows very high usage on half the cores/threads, but the others are mostly **idle**.

On the assumption that this is something related to process affinity, I ran taskset on the PID of an affected process:

```
taskset -p 19222
pid 19222's current affinity mask: fc0fc0
```

*fc0fc0 meaning cores 6-11 & 18-23 (observable in htop)*

Following the parent processes up the chain, the affinity mask 'fc0fc0' appears to have been inherited from /usr/bin/plasma_session (which taskset reports as 'fc0fc0').  The parent process of plasma_session, /usr/bin/startplasma-x11 has affinity mask 'ffffff' (all cores).   Its not always fc0fc0 though - Sometimes its '3f03f' (cores 0-5 & 12-17) if its a different login session, or I've rebooted.

When I launch a console session (via Ctrl-Alt-F2), the same (software video encoding) processes utilize all cores as desired.

I know I can manually reset the affinity of processes via taskset (back to 'ffffff' or '0-23' to utilize all cores), and then see new processes inherit the mask and work as desired:

```bash
for i in $(pgrep -u $(whoami)); do
 taskset -ap ffffff $i
done
```

My question is what could be causing this to happen in the first place, and how can I stop it, rather than using a silly script like the one above?

After a lot of searching around, I'm guessing it may have something to do with cgroups, but I can't find any configuration files that would obviously (to me) be causing this behavior.